Jordanian citizen overstayed in the US
My fiance is a citizen of Jordan and I am a US citizen. He came to New York on a B1/B2 visa. He received it for 5 years thinking he was allowed to remain in the US without returning home every 6 months. He went back to Jordan in 2019, and hasn't been able to come back since he overstayed longer than 180 days.
Any information or suggestions on what can be done?  As it stands, it seems he is banned from returning to the US for 10 years.

How long exactly did he overstay? https://www.uscis.gov/laws-and-policy/other-resources/unlawful-presence-and-inadmissibility Why have you tagged your question ‘green card’? Does he want to return to visit or to immigrate?
